# Using Hostgator Domain on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I am trying to use my hostgator registered domain on my node.js application deployed through heroku.

I have added the domain to my heroku application through the custom domain feature, and when i type "Heroku Domains" in the console, it shows up with a target of: "photosbysalwa.com.herokudns.com" and a type of ALAIS or ANAME.

When I try to add an ANAME record through hostgator, I try to set the address to "photosbysalwa.com.herokudns.com" but it won't let me submit the record because it says the address must be an IP address.

If you could help me with how to get the domain pointed, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Check this video its about how to point your domain name to heroku hosting.
It have godaddy domain name and its the same way to hostgator I think

in the heroku page in the settings add three domains:

```
1 *.xyz.com 
2: xyz.com
3. www.xyz.com
```

open your Hostgator account and in the DNS Management page add in the cname the host: www and in the point to: your heroku url

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKGSGT7mSnQ&t=9s
I believe this will solve your problem